# Преобразование значений в столбцах в дату

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется sql таблица, в которой дата разбита по столбцам year, month, day со значениями int.
Как проще всего собрать значения в отдельный столбец с типом date.
Пробовал вычисляемым столбцом, но тип столбца берется на основе вычисляемых.

Comment: SQL SERVER 13.0.4259.0

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=038385a51f7081f3e62ee56f189665be

Comment: Афигеть как просто. Спасибо.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7d28510b35d36337af8c5ca4b7dff33a